# remove private internet access

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, uninstall

```
mudit@mudit-Presario:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove pia
[sudo] password for mudit: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for mudit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'pia' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
mudit@mudit-Presario:~$
```

Help me!
it says its not installed
i think i interrupted uninstall once

tried reinstall but not working

```
mudit@mudit-Presario:~$ sudo apt-get install pia
[sudo] password for mudit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  xawtv-plugins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pia xawtv-plugins
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 87.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 595 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 xawtv-plugins amd64 3.103-4build1 [52.8 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 pia amd64 3.103-4build1 [34.4 kB]
Fetched 87.2 kB in 3s (25.6 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package xawtv-plugins.
(Reading database ... 176217 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xawtv-plugins_3.103-4build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xawtv-plugins (3.103-4build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pia.
Preparing to unpack .../pia_3.103-4build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pia (3.103-4build1) ...
Setting up xawtv-plugins (3.103-4build1) ...
Setting up pia (3.103-4build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
mudit@mudit-Presario:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove pia
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pia xawtv-plugins
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
After this operation, 595 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 176269 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pia (3.103-4build1) ...
Removing xawtv-plugins (3.103-4build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
mudit@mudit-Presario:~$
```

[Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODi4e.png)

Comment: Can you try to reinstall it and then remove it without interrupting?

Comment: The Ubuntu repositories has a `pia` package, which is some kind of movie player. Apparently, it has nothing to do with the [PIA VPN](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/). This should do it: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/kb/articles/how-can-i-uninstall-reinstall-your-application-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @mikewhatever said, the "pia" package you're trying to uninstall never is your Private Internet Access application; they're both different.

#### Uninstalling Private Internet Access:

Since PIA was installed from binary files, all you have to do is remove the files.

Remove PIA Config: `rm -rf ~/.config/PrivateInternetAccess`

Remove APPIcon: `rm ~/.local/share/applications/pia_manager.desktop`

Remove Binary Files: `sudo rm -rf /opt/pia`, `rm -rf ~/.pia_manager`

Remove directory that starts with `.pia_*` from your home directory, it's okay if it's not there.

Uninstalling package like this can always be predicted from how you installed it first & yeah as always google first.