# How to remove Private Internet Access vpn servers from my network connection?

Tags: uninstall, vpn, software-uninstall

[image]

I have already done what the below two links say but still have these pia servers showing up in my system. How can I completely remove it.

[Linux - Uninstalling the PIA App through the Terminal](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/guides/linux/linux-uninstalling-the-pia-app-through-the-terminal#linux-uninstalling-the-pia-app-through-the-terminal_step-3-commands)

[remove private internet access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108824/remove-private-internet-access)

**EDIT**: In case links become dead in the future, Listing here all the commands that I ran from the above two links:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/privateinternetaccess
rm -rf ~/.config/PrivateInternetAccess
sudo rm -rf /opt/piavpn
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/applications/piavpn.desktop
rm ~/.local/share/applications/pia_manager.desktop
sudo rm -rf /opt/pia
rm -rf ~/.pia_manager
```

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @waltinator Agree with you. Updated post as per your feedback.